# How to localize pdf.js toolbar?

Tags: javascript, localization, locale, pdf.js

I'm using Mozilla's [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) plugin. I want to know how to localize the toolbar into my native language. Which function will help?

Comment: there are multiple localization libraries available that will automatyically set up the language. You need to import the correct library for that. Please visit this link ... https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/l10n

Comment: Now I find the way for it ! The set up language function is in the viewer.js file. This is the below function.

 mozL10n.setLanguage('vi');

Answer (score 6):

Now I find the way for it ! The set up language function is in the viewer.js file. This is the below function.

mozL10n.setLanguage(locale);

Where locale is you native language .

Comment: How can I issue this command if I iframe viewer.html? My current way is bring a lang=xx query parameter and hack viewer.js to check location.href to set appropriate locale. But I really don't hack any files bundled with pdf.js, include viewer.html and viewer.js.

Comment: pdf.js default to value of navigator.language but that depends on browser's option setting. What if I use locale-A browser but I want to change it to local-B? The HTML  lang attribute doesn't help since it can't change value of navigator.language.

Answer (score 1):

The `pdf.js` viewer itself reads the locality from the browser by default.
The way I found to override that setting lays in editing the default property in `./web/viewer.js` file. See the lines: 237-240.

By the time of writing this answer I'm using the following build `viewerVersion = '2.11.209'`.

So it has to be changed from:

```
  defaultOptions.locale = {
    value: typeof navigator !== "undefined" ? navigator.language : "en-US",
    kind: OptionKind.VIEWER
  };
```

to the following:

```
  defaultOptions.locale = {
    value: "de-DE", // change the locale to yours here
    kind: OptionKind.VIEWER
  };
```

**Note:** in the sample above I'm using the German locale, which leads to `"de-DE"` value.